# How to deal with the following error code:

Tags: c, cs50

I've just started the CS50 online class offered through Harvard online and I'm struggling with the assignment from week 1. The goal is to have the use input some amount of change and have the program output the minimum number of total coins (in quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies) required to make that change. I keep getting the following error for my code: error: expected identifier or '(' at the first {. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int coins(int quarters, int dimes, int nickels, int pennies)
    int quarters = 25;
    int dimes = 10;
    int nickels = 5;
    int pennies = 1;
    int remain = 0;
    int place_holder;
{
    while (cents >= quarters)
    {
        remain = cents % quarters;
        place_holder = cents - remain;
        coins = coins + (place_holder / quarters);
        cents = remain;
    }

    return coins;
    printf("%i\n", coins);
}
```

Comment: `coins` is a function, not a variable that you can assign.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `remain` and `placeholder` are local variables which should be moved down below the first `{` where the function's code block begins. Best refer to a C book. Also, note that the last line `printf("%i\n", coins);` will never be reached, because it follows the `return` from the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my initial thought on the specific cause of the error was correct.  But I do see multiple issues:

- You can't assign to `coins`, which is the name of the function itself.  You need to declare a local variable to hold the result
- You have a statement after the `return` statement.  `return` means you will exit from the function. The `printf` wouldn't ever be executed.  I'm not sure if the compiler will allow this at all. Even if it does, you won't see your output.
- I'm not certain about the syntax you are using to declare and initialize variables and parameters.  I think that at least the declarations of local variables (`remain` and `place_holder`) need to be in the function body, but I'm not certain.
- You have a reference to `cents`, but you don't declare it anywhere (at least that's shown)

When I'm getting started with a new programming language, I tend to start writing functions that do absolutely nothing, to make sure I have the basic syntax correct.  Then I start adding individual lines and testing that they compile and execute.  I think this makes it easier to understand where errors are coming from.  Maybe you would find it helpful to take this approach.

Comment: Yes.  I believe the problem lies with `coins` being used as a variable when it is a function.

Comment: Upon further review, there may be issues with both.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons No, it's not valid K&R C.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Agreed.  I did a little more digging into exactly how the K&R style worked since I'm only vaguely familiar with it as I have never actually seen it in the wild.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons actually, in the K&R definition the parameter data types would be outside the parentheses.  Inside would simply be the variable names (quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies) int quarters;...  ANSI style moved the types inside the parentheses.  For the record, my first work in C was on a PDP-11 using a Mark Williams C compiler... which is to say, I'm old.